# Excel crashes on opening a module in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to macros but I attempted building one, a pretty elaborate one in fact! After the last validation piece that I included in my code, excel crashes every time I try to open the module where i coded most part of my macro.  This happens even when i try to save the workbook that contains this macro.  I am able to open other modules within this workbook and any other excel workbook.  The problem seems to persist only with one particular module after I added an if condition at the beginning of a subroutine.  Basically, below is what i tried that I believe makes excel to crash every time I try to do anything with this macro:

```
Sub Process()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("XFD2").Value <> 2 Then
  MsgBox "Create reports first!"
  Else
    'Lot of other stuff
End If
End Sub
```

Every time I try to open this module, windows says Microsoft excel stopped working and then i get another pop that leaves me with no other option but to close the program. I have attached the screen shot of the message.

[image: Excel Message]

I searched online and got to know such problems arise when a program is installed that would crash with Microsoft program, but I did not install anything new and also checked the add-ins to excel in safe mode, I see no com add-ins.

I would have removed that last condition, but excel does not allow me to open the subroutine. I have invested a lot of time building this macro, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Agree with @KyloRen, this shouldn't be causing Excel to crash. Try stepping through your code with F8 to find exactly what the error is. I can only assume it's somewhere in `'Lot of other stuff`

Comment: @KyloRen/@Sam:Thanks for your comments.  I somehow managed to open and recover the code.  I simply pasted the code in new workbook and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Macro should not be causing Excel to crash, either the way you are saving the file is causing the error or you have a problem with its installation.

And make sure you set those reset `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts` to true,

```
Sub Process()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("XFD2").Value <> 2 Then
  MsgBox "Create reports first!"
  Else
    'Lot of other stuff
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Aqua, your only recourse is to re-install excel if you can't locate the problem. And when exiting the macro, you will need to re-activate those, otherwise they will be disabled.